# time series dataset train test split ML

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, time-series, xgboost

On [machinelearningmastery there is a post](https://machinelearningmastery.com/convert-time-series-supervised-learning-problem-python/) about how to create a supervised learning regression type dataset from one time series variable.

For example this:

```
time, measure
1, 100
2, 110
3, 108
4, 115
5, 120
```

Can be turned into this below after passing the data through a function `series_to_supervised`

```
X, y
?, 100
100, 110
110, 108
108, 115
115, 120
120, ?
```

In the ***Multi-Step or Sequence Forecasting*** section of the machinelearningmastery post, the `series_to_supervised` can output this below:

```
   var1(t-2)  var1(t-1)  var1(t)  var1(t+1)
2        0.0        1.0        2        3.0
3        1.0        2.0        3        4.0
4        2.0        3.0        4        5.0
5        3.0        4.0        5        6.0
6        4.0        5.0        6        7.0
7        5.0        6.0        7        8.0
8        6.0        7.0        8        9.0
```

My question is how would I define the X & y train test split? I am assuming the `var1(t)` would be the defined as y, right? For example would this be correct below for trainX & trainy? I am experimenting with

```
#function for time series X,y breakdown
train = series_to_supervised(need_to_train,11,14)

#split data sets
trainX = np.array(train.drop(['var1(t)'],1))
trainy = np.array(train['var1(t)'])

model = XGBRegressor(objective='reg:squarederror', n_estimators=100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `var1(t+1)` would be the target and taken as `y`. The whole point is to predict the next step in the future from the current (and past) data.

Comment: Would you have any tips on how I can slice the data for train test split? So I think the last column in the dataframe would always be the target variable then, right?

Comment: @HenryHub That's quite common but not universal. You should think about what your target variable is - what is it you're trying to predict? Your code looks fine, you just targetted the wrong column that's all.

Comment: One last newbie question sorry, If I am experimenting with many past observations and several future observations, IE, `var1(t-2)  var1(t-1)  var1(t)  var1(t+1) var1(t+2) var1(t+3) var1(t+4)`, would my target variable always be `var1(t+1)`?

Comment: I am experimenting with multioutput regression on hourly data. Trying to forecast a days worth of future data. 24 hours/predictions

Comment: @HenryHub If you have multiple predictions to make you either need to use multiple outputs (and thus multiple target variables), or multiple predictors (one for each target variable).

Comment: Would you have a link or anything where I could read up on some of this info you mention? thank you so much

Comment: Would there be any chance you could give me a tip with this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64897499/time-series-block-chain-how-to

Comment: @HenryHub Please don't personally ask me to answer your questions.